# how to custom a webgrid template or similar function in mvc3!

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

**webgrid is Easy to use ,in mvc3 but the parameter is too many， each page need to set the parameter is so so terrible,
Is there any way to fixed a few parameter in Templates , for example to fix :**

```
                  tableStyle: "webgrid-table"
                 , headerStyle: "webgrid-header"
                 , alternatingRowStyle: "alt"
                 , selectedRowStyle: ""
                 , displayHeader: true
                 , numericLinksCount: 10
                 , footerStyle: "paging-number"
                 , rowStyle: "webgrid-row"
```

**and common columns  delete,add,edit**

grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(" "
                       , "add"
                         , null
                        , new { @class = "webgrid-add", title = " add row", onclick = "return gridop(this);" }))
                     , grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(" "
                          , "edit"
                            , null
                              , new { id = item[0]}
                              , new { @class = "webgrid-edit", title = "edit row", onclick = "return gridop(this);" }))
                     , grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(" "
                                   , "del"
                                 , null
                                    , new { id = item[0]}
                                     , new { @class = "webgrid-del", title = " delete row", onclick = "return gridop(this);" }))

**If completed before the code，When we are ready to show webgrid， only to coding " showgrid(Model); " in page;**

---

gridmodel.cshtml

@model IEnumerable
@{
 var grid = new WebGrid(Model,rowsPerPage:10);

```
if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1)
{
@ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText;
}
else
{

    List<WebGridColumn> columns = new List<WebGridColumn>();
    columns.Add(grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(" "
                   , "add"
                    , null
                    , new { @class = "webgrid-add", title = " 添加新记录！", onclick = "return gridop(this);" })));

    columns.Add(grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(" "
                          , "edit"
                          , null
                         , new { @class = "webgrid-edit", title = " 编辑本行记录信息！", onclick = "return gridop(this);" })));
    columns.Add(grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(" "
                           , "del"
                            , null
                             , new {id = item[1] }
                               , new { @class = "webgrid-del", title = " 删除本行记录信息！", onclick = "return gridop(this);" })));                                                                    



                   if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1)
{
@ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText;
}
                   else
                   {

                       foreach (var item in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForEdit &&
                                                                                                      !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm)))
                       {

                           if (!item.HideSurroundingHtml)
                           {
                               columns.add(new WebGridColumn { ColumnName = item.PropertyName, Header = item.DisplayName });
                           }

                       }
                   }

    var a = grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid-table"
                 , headerStyle: "webgrid-header"
                 , alternatingRowStyle: "alt"
                 , selectedRowStyle: ""
                 , displayHeader: true
                 , caption: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                 , numericLinksCount: 10
                 , footerStyle: "paging-number"
                 , rowStyle: "webgrid-row"
                 , columns: grid.Columns(columns.ToArray()


               )
               );

  @Html.Raw(a.ToString());
           }

}
```

**over is my code ,but ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties is null, can't to retrieve item.PropertyName,
 item.DisplayName . I do not know why！
Please help me !**

Answer (score 0):

Please try using [optional, named parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx). I mean, define the same default values in your control. This control should be an extension method of HtmlHelper class. Thus you can make from your View(s):

@Html.MyGrid(Model)

I commonly create a /Helpers folder for that purpose.

Hope this helps,